# Creating a loop for a pairwise "all vs all" comparison of multiple objects

Tags: r

I would like to do a pairwise "all vs. all" combination of multiple data frames, in my case with the Mantel test.

I have about 50 different matrices I want to compare:
Obj1, Obj2, Obj3, ..., Objn

```
library(vegan)
mantel(Obj1, Obj2)
```

Can I loop through this for all combinations, possibly omitting the redundant pairs? So, only doing one half of the `n * (n-1)/2`?

I am collecting the results into a dataframe:

```
result <- data.frame(mantel_r = NA, significance = NA)
mant <- mantel(Obj1, Obj2)
result[01, c("mantel_r", "significance")] <- mant[3:4]
```

Is it possible to combine the loop with this basic code? Possibly with giving names to the rows of the result.dataframe according to the input?

Comment: You should specify the package that has the `mantel` function. Is it in `library(ecodist)`

Comment: I have, sorry, it was vegan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am guessing the `mantel` is from `vegan`

```
library(vegan)   
names1 <- ls(pattern="Obj")
names1 #I created 3 matrices with names starting with Obj
#[1] "Obj1" "Obj2" "Obj3"

Cmb1 <- combn(names1, 2)
lst1 <- lapply(split(Cmb1, col(Cmb1)), function(x) unlist(mantel(get(x[1]), get(x[2]))[3:4]))
```

#### Update

I am assuming that you want the `list` elements to have some names.

```
names(lst1) <- sapply(lst1, function(x) { paste(paste(names(x), x, sep="_"), collapse="_") })

lst1
```

Comment: thanks, it works well. One more question, in the output $`1`
statistic    signif 
0.3697056 0.0060000 
 is it possible to write the object pair in the line starting with $?