# Replacing the names of list objects with names within a character-object

Tags: r

I have 25 different distance matrices, which i want to compare.
Here a four:

```
dist.merry <- matrix(rnorm(100),10,10)  
dist.pip <- matrix(runif(100),10,10)  
dist.frodo <- matrix(rnorm(100),10,10)  
dist.sam  <- matrix(runif(100),10,10)
```

I write all possible pairs into a character object with two rows and six columns:

```
Cmb1 <- combn(ls(pattern="dist"), 2)
str(Cmb1)
chr [1:2, 1:6] "dist.frodo" "dist.merry" "dist.frodo" "dist.pip" "dist.frodo" "dist.sam" "dist.merry" ..
```

I then perform pairwise mantel tests and save the results in a list.

```
library(vegan)
results <- lapply(split(Cmb1, col(Cmb1)), function(x) unlist(mantel(get(x[1]), get(x[2]), perm=999, "pearson")[3:4]))
```

I fail writing the names onto the list objects.

This is a follow up of a [very old question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25974082/creating-a-loop-for-a-pairwise-all-vs-all-comparison-of-multiple-objects?rq=1). The part of the  anwer which dealt with renaming the list objects seem to fail now.

The question is how i can write the pairwise combinations into the names of the result list?

Comment: Can you show what the names should be? For element one from `results` for example - `"dist.frodo"` or `"dist.merry"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand the requirement correctly, but this would work:

```
names(results) <- unlist(lapply(split(Cmb1, col(Cmb1)), toString))
```

It gives:

```
names(results) 
# [1] "dist.frodo, dist.merry" "dist.frodo, dist.pip"   "dist.frodo, dist.sam"   "dist.merry, dist.pip"  
# [5] "dist.merry, dist.sam"   "dist.pip, dist.sam"
```

If you would like a different separator instead of the `,`, you could use `paste()` with a custom `collapse` argument:

```
names(results) <- unlist(lapply(split(Cmb1, col(Cmb1)), paste, collapse = "_"))
```